# How do I use Chinese co-reference in Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2?

Tags: stanford-nlp

Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 is out and includes Chinese co-reference
How do I use Chinese co-reference? it only include one file "zh-attributes.txt.gz"

thanks,

dev

Comment: 我按标准例子可以执行完成，但没有出正确结果。哪位朋友有没有正确运行出结果的，可否给一个配置过程及实际例子?
I did run out the standard examples, but did not get the correct results. If you can run out the correct results, please give me a practical example of the configuration process. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 1):

For running on plain text, make sure you have Chinese related models on classpath and try the following:

```
    String text = "Your text here";
    String[] args = new String[]{
      "-props", "edu/stanford/nlp/hcoref/properties/zh-dcoref-default.properties"
    };

    Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
    Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties(args);
    StanfordCoreNLP corenlp = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
    corenlp.annotate(document);
    HybridCorefAnnotator hcoref = new HybridCorefAnnotator(props);
    hcoref.annotate(document);
    Map corefChain = document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class); 
    System.out.println(corefChain);
```

In addition we also have documentation for how to run on CoNLL 2012 data [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml#Usage)

Comment: there is no "hcoref" directory in 3.5.2 models   :(

Comment: thank you !  i get it in new models!
when i run example, say lost "demonyms.txt", and i copy "stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models/edu/standford/nlp/modeles/dcoref/" to "stanford-chinese-corenlp-2015-04-20-models/edu/standford/nlp/modeles/dcoref/",

Comment: 1, According to the above suggeetion, i have  checked several times, but  correct results didn't appeared ,it  always show "{}"
2, how to integrate prop  including word segmentation 、  NER、 parse and coref,  i tried but there isn't  correct result display. According to the directory in models, is hcoref a separate system?

Comment: @itdev You need A) the new Chinese corenlp model file, B) Chinese segmentation model file and C) the basic corenlp model file on the classpath for it to load all the relevant resources. 

The naming is a bit confusing, the Chinese system is still deterministic, however its code is integrated with the hcoref package.

Answer (score 1):

Hi we just released some new versions of the 3.5.2 jars with some patches and I wanted to leave this answer here for people.

If you go to: http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/corenlp.shtml

and download Stanford CoreNLP 3.5.2 and the corresponding "chinese models" (the file is called stanford-chinese-corenlp-2015-04-20-models.jar) you will have the jars you need to run Chinese co-reference.

You need stanford-corenlp-3.5.2.jar , stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models.jar , and stanford-chinese-corenlp-2015-04-20-models.jar in your classpath.

Also you can get the exact same jars from the stanford-corenlp project on Maven.  We have just released the Chinese models jar on Maven as well.  Here is how to add it to your pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.5.2</version>
   <classifier>models-chinese</classifier>
</dependency>
```

Just to provide you with something to cut and paste, the test class code Xiao wrote is provided below with needed imports.  I omitted the sample Chinese text, so set String text to the sample Chinese text you want to run on.

This should be run with a command like this: java -mx5g -cp "location-of-jars/*:." ChineseCorefTester -props edu/stanford/nlp/hcoref/properties/zh-dcoref-default.properties

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Set;

import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefCoreAnnotations.CorefChainAnnotation;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.CorefSystem;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.CorefChain;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.CorefChain.CorefMention;
import edu.stanford.nlp.hcoref.data.Document;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreLabel;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.ArraySet;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.CoreMap;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Generics;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.IntTuple;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.Pair;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.StringUtils;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.io.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.ling.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.trees.TreeCoreAnnotations.*;
import edu.stanford.nlp.util.*;

public class ChineseCorefTester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String text = "<insert sample Chinese text here!>";
        Annotation document = new Annotation(text);
        Properties props = StringUtils.argsToProperties(args);
        StanfordCoreNLP corenlp = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
        corenlp.annotate(document);
        HybridCorefAnnotator hcoref = new HybridCorefAnnotator(props);
        hcoref.annotate(document);
        System.out.println(document.get(CorefChainAnnotation.class));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you, i can run example no error. but , no one result too;
txten="Kosgi Santosh sent an email to Stanford University. He didn't get a reply.";
txtcn="凯特发了一封邮件给斯坦福大学,他没有收到回复.";
and log is:

Loading sieve: StrictHeadMatch2 ...
Loading sieve: StrictHeadMatch3 ...
Loading sieve: StrictHeadMatch4 ...
Loading sieve: PronounMatch ...
SEMANTICS NOT LOADED
MentionExtractor ignores specified annotators, using annotators=lemma, ner
Registering annotator segment with class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ChineseSegmenterAnnotator
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
{}

Comment: I as well am getting the empty output.  I don't have a deep knowledge of the Chinese co-ref system, so it is possible the system just failed to see the connection between "Kosgi" and "He."  That doesn't mean it is functioning improperly ; keep in mind the system is not guaranteed to find all coreferences with 100% accuracy.

Comment: That being said, I will see if I can get some insight into why that sentence has no result.

Comment: So what I learned is that we don't have "Kosgi" in our gender dictionary, so we don't have a definitive gender for that name.  So the system in this case isn't making an attachment.  One future improvement for the system is expanding the dictionaries, etc...

Answer (score 0):

thank you !  i get it in new models!
when i run example, say lost "demonyms.txt", and i copy "stanford-corenlp-3.5.2-models/edu/standford/nlp/modeles/dcoref/" to "stanford-chinese-corenlp-2015-04-20-models/edu/standford/nlp/modeles/dcoref/",
and then
`code`
[凯特, 发, 了, 一, 封, 邮件, 给, 斯坦福, ，, 他, 没有, 收到, 回复, 。]
Loading sieve: ChineseHeadMatch ...
Loading sieve: ExactStringMatch ...
Loading sieve: PreciseConstructs ...
Loading sieve: StrictHeadMatch1 ...
Loading sieve: StrictHeadMatch2 ...
Loading sieve: StrictHeadMatch3 ...
Loading sieve: StrictHeadMatch4 ...
Loading sieve: PronounMatch ...
SEMANTICS NOT LOADED
MentionExtractor ignores specified annotators, using annotators=lemma, ner
Registering annotator segment with class edu.stanford.nlp.pipeline.ChineseSegmenterAnnotator
Adding annotator lemma
Adding annotator ner
null
`code`